# In JavaFx How To Create Dotted Line Around The Text Box of a Button That Has Focus

Tags: javafx

How do I create a dotted-line around the text in a button when it has focus? I don't want in around the actual characters, it needs to be around the box that contains the text.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this, but it only seems practical for large buttons as the border takes up space inside the button and enlarges it.

For starters you'll need something like the following in your css file. [See CSS docs for more info.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html)

```
.buttonBorder { -fx-label-padding: 10; }
.buttonBorder:focused {
    -fx-label-padding: 0;
    -fx-border-style: dashed;
    -fx-border-color: red;
    -fx-border-insets: 10;
    -fx-border-width: 1;
    -fx-border-radius: 2;
}
```

Add the style class to the button:

```
Button but = new Button( "Some Text" );
but.getStyleClass().add( "buttonBorder" );
```